# Overriding media query through order precedence

Tags: css, media-queries

The 600px media query is not applying.  Since it does have order precedence, shouldn't it apply?

```
#mydiv {color:#FF0000;}
@media screen and (max-width:750px){
    #mydiv {color:#000;}
}
@media screen and (max-width:600px){
    #mydiv {color:#33CC33;}
}

<div id="mydiv">
    testing text color with media queries
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpnGh/3/

Comment: I had the same issue. w3 schools doesn't make it clear there. If you check the chrome developer panel and experiment a bit, you'll see that the classes of *latest media query* execution stand of priority if *multiple classes* apply. So say had you given 'mydiv1' a property in >750px, and 'mydiv2' for >600px, and declared a div with class='mydiv1 mydiv2' and have a screen of 1000px, where both classes apply by rule, 'mydiv2' will take precedence, irrespective of order (='mydiv1 mydiv2', ='mydiv2 mydiv1').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sample works fine here in Chrome nightly with 3 colors?

Nevertheless, never count on order precedence, be explicit:

```
    @media screen and (max-width:750px) and (min-width:601px)
```

Will solve any issues right away and make your code easier to maintain.